# New tab in WPF - items.add from buttons vs methods

Tags: wpf, tabs, routed-events

OK, so I have a window called PictureWindow which displays pictures (I've cut out the code not related to making tabs). The TabControl is named "itemsTab". Using a button press, I can make a new tab no problem. But using the same operations inside a called method doesn't work. Using the buttonTab_Click method makes a new tab, the newTab method does not.

The only real difference I can see is due to the sender and RoutedEventArgs objects - how do these effect the operation here? Or is there something else I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

*Edit* To make things even stranger, the newTab method does make a new tab, but only if it is called in the PictureWindow constructor method. If I have the following a new tab is made.

```
        
public PictureWindow(string current)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            newTab(current);
        }
```

But if I call the method anywhere else it doesn't work.

```
public partial class PictureWindow : Window
    {
        public PictureWindow(string current)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void buttonClose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void buttonTab_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TabItem newTab = new TabItem();
            newTab.Header = "New Tab!";
            itemsTab.Items.Add(newTab);
        }

        public void newTab(string current)
        {
            TabItem newTab = new TabItem();
            itemsTab.Items.Add(newTab);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint and check that newTab() really gets called?

Comment: Yes, I have. Both get called correctly and execute with the same data. But only one actually makes the new tab.

Comment: Just in case anybody else makes this dumb mistake, I'm posting the solution to the problem. The new Tab item was made and added, but not to a current window.
`var newWindow = new PictureWindow(fileName);
var window = newWindow.getCurrentPictureWindow();
window.newTab(fileName);`

By using the getCurrentPictureWindow to select the right window, the tab was added successfully.